# Can a regional domain beat a .com one all other things being equal?

Tags: seo, domains

This is a theoretical question.

Asumming that one example is named `something.[ccTLD]` and the second one is named `somethingelse.com`

Both websites have same quality content (I know it is hard to compare but it is a theoretical scenario).

Both websites have the same number of backlinks, content quantity as well and of course are rivals and have similar topic and industry.

I am curious if only the domain ending can affect the search results in such a degree that the first domain does not rank globally but second one ranks

So my question is how important do you think the domain ending is in this case for SEO ranking ?

Answer (score 2):

The ccTLD site will only rank in its country because it is geo-targeted. When a site has a ccTLD it signals that it is explicitly intended for a certain country. It is strict by design.

The gTLD has the ability to rank wherever. It can geo-target content via [`hreflang`](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/tags/hreflang/info) but users might not recognize this solely from the URL.

The importance depends on where the site owner wants their content to appear in search results.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. So we can conclude and say that a ccTLD is doomed and cannot compete internationally even if it uses hreflang and supports multiple languages as well like example.ccTLD/en/blabla /de/blabla etc

Comment: For many websites a ccTLD is a great option. It is just a country specific website.

Comment: I am using a ccTLD and suffering a lot. My `en` content is never ranking well in seo , on the other hand within the country my content in original language ranks fine. (I test the google search with VPN and noticed this). Overall it sucks after putting lot of effort in blog posts in international language and never ranking being penalised due to just a domain name

Comment: Have to think of rebrading and finding a .com then...

Comment: Keep your ccTLD website. Make a separate website targeting international users with translated content and proper geo-targeting.

Comment: Good advice thanks Mike. Maybe I can keep my ccTLD and redirect `/en` to the new domain right ? In that case have to think of a similar name for my .com domain and plan properly this "migration".

Comment: What about english speaking users that live in your country? Is this a concern? Additionally, if you 301 `/en` to international site think about possible semantic or link signals that it might inherit. I would not redirect `/en` to a new international site. They should co-exist in my opinion.

Comment: Ok maybe I misunderstood. But if I have a new website with the same content of my existing one and similar name would not the people get confused ? For instance electronics.at and electronics.com. Both have exactly same content and compete for same keywords and seo..

Comment: Read about international SEO, you will find the answers. Aleyda Solis has a deck I like https://www.slideshare.net/aleydasolis/cost-effective-multilingual-content-optimization-in-an-international-seo-process